# code under modal operator gets executed only when mouse is moved or a key is pressed

Tags: python, operator

i have the following code to receive serial data from arduino and rotate the cube...

```
import bpy
from bpy import context
import serial
from time import sleep
from bpy.props import IntProperty, FloatProperty


value = 0
i=0
j=0
degree = 0
ser = serial.Serial("COM77", 9600)

class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
  bl_idname = "object.modal_operator"
  bl_label = "Simple Modal Operator"

x = IntProperty()

def modal(self, context, event):
   if ser.inWaiting()>0 :
        value = ser.read(2)
        print(value)
        self.x = int(value)
        print(self.x)
        self.x += 1000
        degree = self.x * 3.14/180
        print(degree)
        bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[0] = degree

   if event.type  == 'LEFTMOUSE':
       return {'FINISHED'}
       ser.close()

   return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

def invoke(self, context, event):
    if context.object:

        print("hi")

        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
    else:
        self.report({'WARNING'}, "No active object, could not finish")
        return {'CANCELLED'}


def register():
   bpy.utils.register_class(ModalOperator)


def unregister():
   bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalOperator)


   register()

# test call

bpy.ops.object.modal_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

the code under invoke function executes immediately when i run the script..but the statements under modal function executes only if i move the mouse or press any key...

I think it doesn't consider incoming serial data as an event...

i want the serial data to be read as and wen it comes...not only wen the mouse is moved..

Is there any way to check serial event....  like  'MOUSE_MOVE'  or 'LEFTMOUSE'....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are looking for probably, is running a timer alongside the modal operator, so you can check the serial data whenever the operator gets executed with a timer event.

There already is a code template in blender, that shows you how to do this.
Look for the **Template** menu entry at the bottom of the Text Editor and select **Python > Operator Modal Timer**

The relevant code is in the execute function:

```
wm = context.window_manager
self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.1, context.window)
```

The 0.1 controls the time interval between successive timer events in seconds.

Then you can check for a timer event in modal with:

```
if event.type == 'TIMER':
```

And for cleanup in the cancel function:

```
wm = context.window_manager
wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)
```